# docker fork/exec /proc/self/exe: cannot allocate memory

Tags: docker, fork

After a few days, docker fails with errors

```
docker[8927]: level=error msg="Error running exec in container: execcantrun: Cannot run exec command 34a26 in container 4972e576: [8] System error: fork/exec /proc/self/exe: cannot allocate memory\n"
```

Docker 1.9.1 (upgrade is not an option)

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ     RSS    TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND 
root         34763  9.3    0.8    10680004   535208   ?      Ssl  Mar13 1334:17 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --insecure-registry=0.0.0.0/0 --log-level=warn --ip-forward=false
```

See VSZ is almost 10G

free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached 
Mem:         63012      60128       2883        816          1       6775 
-/+ buffers/cache:      53351       9660 
Swap:         8191       7581        610
```

If I restart docker service, the issue goes away until reoccurrence after a few days.

After docker restart, VSZ is around 2G

```
root      27144  2.4  0.0 1786272 44432 ?       Ssl  17:44   4:47 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --insecure-registry=0.0.0.0/0 --log-level=warn --ip-forward=false
```

Anyone seen it or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8539 which is resolved in docker 1.10 or later.
There was some issue with docker log driver that resulted in buffer problems specifically for flushing a container's STDOUT.